# How to group the data with Month and sum it using the Apache Common CSV with functional style?

Tags: java, csv, functional-programming, csv-parser

The attached screenshot below is the output of the dataset. This is my homework and I have been required to do all the coding according to the functional programming style. I have try to use Java Stream and map to parse the date, but I have no idea to group them by month and weeks, then sum the data.

[Data Set Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcoJ7.png)

Below is my code:

This is the function to read the file and store the data into arraylist

```
public ArrayList<List<String>> csvParser(String CSVFileName) throws IOException {
        CSVParser csvParser = CSVParser.parse(Paths.get(CSVFileName), Charset.defaultCharset(), CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
        return csvParser
                .stream()
                .map(i->i.toList())
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
```

This is function to retrieve the column of the dataset and parse the date

```
public List<String> parseRetrievedDateList(List<String> dateToBeParsedList){
        return dateToBeParsedList.stream()
                .map(l-> {
                    return LocalDate.parse(l,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/M/d"));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, one option would be to use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...)` [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

For example in your case (guessing on the rest of the code), you could do as follows:

```
parser
   .stream() // stream of csv rows
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CsvRow::getMonth);
```

This returns a map of month (whatever type that is) against a list of rows for that month.

Hope that gives you some guidance.

Comment: Hi, Thomas. I have try the groupingBy. But I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: How to make the call of ```(CsvRow::getMonth)``` recognize the data in data set?

Comment: @mikekong what does the stream contain from the parser?

Comment: the stream contains the covid data set read from csvfile.

Comment: my appologies I should have been clearer, what type is the stream? For example is it a Stream<String> or a Stream<Double> etc...

Comment: It is Stream<String>

Comment: could you possible map it into a new object which represents the various fields in the csv row?

Comment: I dont know how